# How to use regular expression to extract the byte like '<9f><98><82>' from a string in the R

Tags: r, wildcard

I am trying to use r to extract a code like '<9f><98><82>' in order to get the emoji code in a string using R and regular expression but not successful as there are multiple <> in the string. Can some one provide some suggestions of how to use the regular expression to extract it ? I am using separate function now.

eg: for this string 'Sooooo.. this happened <9f><92><8d> \r\n(I said yes) ' I hope to get '<9f><92><8d>'

tried the expression as "<*>"
like

```r
column1 <- separate(TwitterData2,text,into = c("text", "Emojicode"), sep = "<*>")
```

but the result is below attached (masked the username for credential purpose)
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? And what is the expected result?

Comment: A sample string or two would be helpful also be helpful.

Comment: added the details above !  @gersht

Comment: added the detail above ! @Adam

Comment: how about being more explicit with your pattern something like `<[0-9a-f]{2}>` instead of `<*>`

Comment: greedy/lazy regex might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like the following. I've added a few extra cases to show how generalizable this solution is. The `(<.*?>){3,}` says to match any pattern of three or more consecutive `<.*?>`, where the `?` tells R to match non-greedily. It's important that `perl = T` or `{3,}` won't work:

```r
s1 <- 'Sooooo.. this happened <9f><92><8d> \r\n(I said yes) '
regmatches(s1, gregexpr("(<.*?>){3,}", s1, perl = T))

# [[1]]
# [1] "<9f><92><8d>"


s2 <- 'Sooooo.. this happened <9f><92><8d><93> \r\n(I said yes) '
regmatches(s2, gregexpr("(<.*?>){3,}", s2, perl = T))

# [[1]]
# [1] "<9f><92><8d><93>"


s3 <- 'Sooooo.. this happened <9f><92><8d> \r\n(I said yes) <9f><92><8d>'
regmatches(s3, gregexpr("(<.*?>){3,}", s3, perl = T))

# [[1]]
# [1] "<9f><92><8d>" "<9f><92><8d>"
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

I ran this regex on the same test cases @gersht used in their answer.

```
library(stringr)

tststr <- "Sooooo.. this happened <9f><92><8d> \r\n(I said yes)"
str_extract_all(tststr, "(<[0-9a-f]{2}>)+")
# [1] "<9f><92><8d>"

tststr <- "Sooooo.. this happened <9f><92><8d><93> \r\n(I said yes)"
str_extract_all(tststr, "(<[0-9a-f]{2}>)+")
# [[1]]
# [1] "<9f><92><8d><93>"


tststr <- "Sooooo.. this happened <9f><92><8d> \r\n(I said yes) <9f><92><8d>"
str_extract_all(tststr, "(<[0-9a-f]{2}>)+")
# [[1]]
# [1] "<9f><92><8d>" "<9f><92><8d>"
```